# A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. But using AddTransient for dbcontext

Tags: entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am getting following errors. The problem only occurring if there are multiple calls. Checked many posts about this.

I am using `services.AddTransient` for the dbcontext.

> Exception occurred during process Opportunity Priority for submission id  = xxxx, System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913./r/n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()/r/n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()/r/n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)/r/n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)/r/n   at DataAccessLayer.SubmissionDataRepository.GetOpportunityPriority(Nullable`1 submissionId) in /

```cs
public async Task<OpportunityPriorityDto> GetOpportunityPriority(int? submissionId)
{
    if (submissionId == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(submissionId));

    _logger.LogDebug("Retrieving data for Opportunity Priority");
    var subId = new SqlParameter("submission_id", submissionId);

    List<OpportunityPriorityDto> result = await _elmsContext.ProbabilityPercentDto
        .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.pc_polaris_salesforce_opportunity_priority @submission_id", subId).AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync();  // => here is the error.

    _logger.LogInformation($"*** Executed StroredProc --> EXECUTE dbo.pc_polaris_salesforce_opportunity_priority @submission_id, {submissionId.ToString()}");
    return   result != null && result.Count > 0 ? result.FirstOrDefault() : null;
}
```

Comment: I tried scope, transient. Still same error. And also I checked all the await

Comment: If `GetOpportunityPriority` is called without await you can still get this error. You should show the code that calls the method.

Comment: Side note: `submissionId` can't be `null`, so don't make it a nullable parameter. And `result` will never be `null`, you can simply return `result.FirstOrDefault()` which will be `null` when the list is empty.

Comment: If GetOpportunityPriority is called without await you can still get this error. You should show the code that calls the method.
The code calls GetOpportunityPriority has await